# Xamarin forms - Looping through 3 million records comparing closest position coordinates (lat & lng)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I currently have a list of positional coordinates (13). I need to individually compare each position(lat & long) to a record of 3 million to find the closest of each. I'm not sure how to go about this. I thought about a for loop but does not seem efficient to me.

Comment: What is your question?  You haven't provided any detail or code, just a fairly vague scenario.  Can you offload the processing to a server instead of doing it all on a mobile device?  Is the data available in a geospatial db?  There is an entire site (https://gis.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to geospatial questions, this might be a better fit there.  They are probably better suited to provide suggestions about how to efficiently work with large geospatial datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jason to ask it at gis site. Specifically, common problems like these typically can be solved with existing libraries or open source code. I'm out of the loop on what code to use.

But I'm familiar with this, so I'll give a description of two related approaches.

NOTE: Lat/Lng distances MUST be calculated using an appropriate distance function. DO NOT do the "flat space" calculation of `sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)`. REASON: 1 degree in x is a different distance than 1 degree in y, and depends what latitude you are at.

---

**One-Axis Binning**

Because you only have 13 "goal" locations, this will be fast enough. And its easy to code.

- Divide one coordinate axis (e.g. "y") into some large number of equal-length bins. If you don't know what "range" your 3M "reference" points cover, then you'll need to first make a pass to find min/max.
- Add each "reference" point to list in correct bin.
- For each "goal" location, gather points from the corresponding bin. If there are none, then take the two neighboring bins. Expand from original bin until you find at least one "reference" point. Make a "comparison" list of the points in these one or two bins.
- Expand out one bin further in both directions (-y and +y), add those points to "comparison" list. Reason: your point might be near bin edge, so closest point might be "one bin farther away".
- Find the closest of that subset of points.

---

**Two-Axis Binning**

Same as above, but using a 2x2 grid to hold the points.
Overkill given only 13 "goal" points.
But if you later have hundreds of goal points, this becomes worthwhile.

- Divide your space into a grid of equal size "areas". E.g. 256 x 256 "bins". Each area holds a list of coordinates that it contains.
- Put each point in correct bin.
- For each "goal" location, gather points from the same bin, as well as each of the 8 neighboring bins. So you are examining a 3x3 set of bins. Reason: your point might be near bin edge, so closest point might be in different bin.
- Find the closest of that subset of points.
- If the distance to closest < length of bin edge, you are done.
- Otherwise, you need to "expand out one bin", look at 5x5 set.
- If the distance to closest < 2 x length of bin edge, you are done.
- Expand further if necessary. (Usually it isn't, unless you have a very uneven distribution of the large coordinate set.)

Comment: I'm ashamed to ask, but can you give an example in code please

Comment: I've got that code somewhere, but would need to extract it from proprietary code. Busy this week; If I don't get around to it, remind me again in one week (next Monday).